# Capture mouse events on SVG element in object, and also it's parent container div

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, pointer-events

I've run into a strange problem with a loaded SVG file in HTML. I'm attaching click events to specific elements in the SVG file, which works fine. But, I also need to attach mouse and touch events to it's parent div. Seems that the SVG object is capturing the mouse events, and therefore they are not bubbling up to the parent div. So, I try to set pointer-event on the SVG to none. In this case, the parent div receives mouse events, but now the child SVG element is no longer getting the mouse events. I try to set the child svg element to pointer-events: all, but still it is not getting the mouse events. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is how I am embedding the SVG file:

```
 <div
  id="map"
  ng-pinchable
  scale-factor="2"
  max-zoom="2"
 >
   <object data="./media/map.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
     id="mapsvg" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>
```

Here is how I am adding events to the SVG element via JS:

```
//add event listeners to stations
                var el = $scope.svgDoc.getElementById("station-test");
      el.style.pointerEvents = "all";
                el.addEventListener("mouseup",
                        function(){
                            $scope.stationClicked("some id");
                        }
                    );
      }, false);
```

And here I am adding events to the parent "map" div that is holding the SVG object:

```
 el.addEventListener("click", function(){ console.log("Hello World!"); });
 el.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){ console.log("mousedown"); });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: getElementById("station-test")  I don't see an element with id 'station-test'. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

OK well, so far I could not figure out why the SVG elements are not getting click events, so I just made a JS function that iterates through all the children, and compares the position of the mouse to the bounding rect of the SVG object, essentially recreating the click behavior as I would expect it to work.

```
$scope.onClickMap = function(event){
  console.log("on click map");
  var markers = $scope.svgDoc.querySelectorAll('*[id^="station"]');
  for(i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
    console.log("found markers: ",markers[i]);
    var rect = markers[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if(event.offsetX > rect.left)
      if(event.offsetX < rect.right)
        if(event.offsetY > rect.top)
          if(event.offsetY < rect.bottom)
            $scope.stationClicked("some id");
  }
```

So it is working for me now, but I would be curious to hear as to why the click events are not triggering/bubbling as expected, if anyone has an idea of a better way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to paste the svg code to html in a <svg> element directly?
It resolves a lot of problems like this often.

Comment: @AliSomay I considered this, but I would rather not do it, since I want to be able to continue editing the SVG file without having to copy and paste the code every time I make a change. Although, I realize I could also create a grunt/gulp task for this sort of thing, it begs the question what is the most efficient route to solving the issue? In my case, I already got it working via the method described above. Thanks for your suggestion however.